# How to change the formatting and Text of a cell based on their values. (Conditional Formatting)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Hi I want to change the Fill color and text of the cell based on its value. Let's say I have the below values.

[image]

And I want to make it like this.

[image]

For me the fill colors would be just easy because I will just do the Conditional formatting. However the text is making it hard. How can I change the cell values into Text like the example above. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your conditional formatting rule(s) for the colors then tap ctrl+1 and apply the following custom number format.

```
[>10]\G\r\e\at\e\r 1\0;[<=10]L\e\s\s 1\0
```

You could put that in the CFR along with the color fill change instead if you want to keep all changes in one place.

Note that you haven't changed the cells' values. `=SUM(Z:Z)` still equals 61.

[image]

Comment: Great! This will also work `[>10]"Greater 10";[<=10]"Less 10"`

Comment: @MarcoVos, I prefer the backslash escape character since I use these in VBA and have a pet peeve against doubling up double quotes.

Comment: Hi thanks. Just a follow up question what if I had a negative value lets say -2. It's outputting "-Less 10" how do I remove the "-" ?

Comment: Try `[>10]\G\r\e\at\e\r 1\0;[<0]L\e\s\s 1\0;L\e\s\s 1\0;`