# Excel statement to return a grade based on two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to create an excel formula that will take the value in column B (Proxy score) and column D (Broker score) then use the calculation in shown in picture 2 to give a grade either , , ✔, , . The values on the left are the Proxy scores (column B) and the values on top are the broker scores (column D)

[image]

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is *excel conditional formatting*.

Comment: @KenWhite not sure if conditional formatting is the way to go here - but a simple INDEX/MATCH would easily work.

Comment: @BigBen: Entirely possible. The poster put the entirety of the sample data into images (inappropriately) that are not available behind most corporate proxies (mine included), which means the content that I have available is what is (properly) included in the textual description. There's also no effort to solve the problem included in order to clarify from that text what is intended.

Comment: You posted how do you do the calculation, but WHERE are you going to show it? Also, I think you could fix this combining format and conditional formatting. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623269/9199828

Answer (score -1):

Just displaying the particular emoji you want is pretty simple, using the `INDEX` function.

```
Proxy Date Time Proxy Score Broker Score    Staff Name      Emoji
12/1/2018 9:24  2           3               Alan Ball       
12/1/2018 11:03 3           2               Adam O'Tough    
12/1/2018 11:44 2           1               Brian King      ✔
```

So let's say you have the emoji definitions in a range, `$C$3:$G$7`:

```
    A       B       C       D       E       F       G
   ----------------------------------------------------------
1 |                            Real             
2 |                 1       2       3       4       5
3 | P       1       ✔       ✔                 
4 | r       2       ✔       ✔                 
5 | o       3                   ✔             
6 | x       4                     ✔       ✔
7 | y       5                     ✔       ✔
```

Now let's assume your data is in a table. To get the appropriate emoji, you'd just use a formula like this: `=INDEX($C$3:$G$7,[@[Proxy Score]],[@[Broker Score]])`